# What does it mean if you assign to a variable with two plus signs?

Tags: c

What does this mean:

```
*variablename++ = ',';
```

I have seen stuff like `i++` which does: `i = i + 1` this I guess.

But what does it mean if you assign a thing to it like the above (first one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common way to assign elements of an array (by using a pointer) inside a loop.

Without knowing the exact type, it's equivalent to something like:

```
{
    type *old_pointer = variablename;  // Substitute type for the actual type

    variablename = variablename + 1;

    *old_pointer = ',';
}
```

---

The important part here is that the variable must be a pointer. You can't do it using non-pointer types like `int`. That's because the suffix increment operator returns an *rvalue* (see e.g. [this value category reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category) for details), and rvalues can't be assigned to.

But if the rvalue is a pointer, then it can be dereferenced to become an lvalue, which can then be assigned to.

Comment: Off-topic question: Is there a way to assign it to a command and a space? Multiple characters not working with it. Why?

Comment: @Simpleperson With a pointer (or an array) `variablename` the expression `*variablename` is exactly equal to `variablename[0]`. It's a single element. If `variablename` is a string then `*variablename` is a single character.

Comment: @Simpleperson you can only assign the type of data that is defined by the destination. If your pointer points to `char`, you can only assign 1 `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Post increment operator `++` has heigher precedence than indirection operator `*`. In addition, the post increment "returns" the previous value of the variable (in our case, the previous value of the pointer before the increment). So the code above is as the same as:

```
*variablename = ',';    
variablename = variablename + 1;
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeap, of course. I've edited the answer.